# Detect automatic change to textarea in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've made a little live preview that detects keyup in a `textarea` and then generates a preview.

```
$('#main-form-subject').children("input").on("change keyup input",function() {
    update_preview(preview_id,subject_id,body_id); 
});
```

Now I also have buttons that insert stuff like image urls automatically to the `textarea`. That obviously doesn't get caught by `keyup`. But also `change` doesn't do the trick. How can I detect these automated changes to the value of a textfield?

Comment: Just do as @Rory McCrossan said. Trigger any of your events after you add the stuff automatically. If you are listening for keyup, trigger keyup, if you are more interested in change trigger change. GL with that and don't make your things more complicated than they have to be.

Answer (score 6):

Changes made programmatically to `input`, `select` and `textarea` elements do not raise events, however you can raise them manually:

```
$('#textarea').val('foo').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting the input field, not textarea field.

```
$('#main-form-subject').children("textarea").on("change keyup input",function() {
   update_preview(preview_id,subject_id,body_id); 
});
```

Comment: sorry, i copied the wrong line. question stays the same though.